# installing 6.0 simulator in xcode 5 giving 403 forbidden error

Tags: ios, xcode, ios-simulator

I am working on an app for ios7 and need support for ios6 as well. I am using xcode 5 and ios7.0 simulator is already installed in it.
I am trying to install ios 6.0 simulator from Preferences -> Downloads -> Components, but it is giving following error "could not download and install ios 6.0 simulator. failed with http status 403"

I searched a lot but could not find solution for it, Can you please help me.

Comment: Did you try to install the 6.1 simulator to see if you get the same error?

Comment: yes, same problem with that as well.

Comment: That seems like a network issue and not xcode issue.

Comment: Thanks Nikos, I will check internet and any firewall which may block it.